# freezing in a multithreaded using condition variable

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, race-condition

With a pseudo-code, I have to implement it in order to parallelize a compute-expensive program (Jacobi iterative method for heat distribution problem).

pseudo-code for Main thread:

```
Create N workers; each with a set of rows
While not max time step or threshold is reached 
   wait for all workers to finish their computation 
   check the max temp diff returned by all workers 
   swap matrices u and w
   if overall max temp diff > ε
     wake up all workers to execute next time step
   else threshold has reached
     wake up all workers and inform them to terminate
   endif
Wait for all workers and print their running statistics 
Get and print master running statistics
Update final_diff
Return no. of temp steps
```

pseudo-code for the worker thread

```
Identify which set of rows to compute
While not terminate yet
   Compute the temp of all points in its set 
   Find the max temp diff in this set
   Signal master to test the diff 
   Wait for master instruction
   if instruction == stop 
      break the while loop
   else instruction == continue 
      continue the while loop
   endif
Get its running statistics and pass it to master 
Terminate
```

I have no idea about why my program got freeze, maybe due to these two reasons:

1. In the main thread, how to "wait for all workers to finish their computation"?
2. In the worker thread, how to "Signal master thread to test the diff"?

My code is as follows:

Main thread

```
    int find_steady_state (void)
{

// (3) Implement the thread creation and the main control logic here

    int thread_rtn;
    int * rptr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mlock, NULL);
   pthread_mutex_init(&nlock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
   pthread_cond_init(&mum, NULL);

    pthread_t thr_kids[thr_count];
    int i_value[thr_count];
   int rtn;
   double **temp;
    
   //Create N thread, according to the input
    for(int i = 0; i < thr_count; ++i){
        i_value[i] = i;
        thread_rtn = pthread_create(&thr_kids[i], NULL, &thr_func, (void*)&i_value[i]);
    }
    
   //run from 1 to max time step
    for(int its = 1; its < max_its; ++its){
      printf("Trial%d, count is %d\n", its, count);

      //find the maximum element in array sum_temp
      //sum_temp stored all the max temp in correspond location, eg: sum_temp[0] = max temp of first thread.
      max_temp = fmax(sum_temp[count], sum_temp[count-1]);

      //Wait for all workers to finish their work
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mlock);
        while(count != 0){
         pthread_cond_wait(&mum, &mlock);
      }

      pthread_mutex_lock(&mlock);
      printf("--- Main thread Wake up!! ---\n");

      //swap the matrix
      temp = u;
      u = w;
      w = temp;
      printf("--- Mother: The matrix is swapped ---\n");

   // test the value, if the value > EPSILON --> wake up all thread to execute next iterations.
   // else, wake up all thread and tell them to terminate.

      if(max_temp > EPSILON){
         stop = false;
         pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&nlock);
         printf("--- Mother: need to continue with temp = %f --- \n", max_temp);
         count = thr_count;
      }
      else{
         stop = true;
         pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&nlock);
         printf("--- Mother: Will Break with temp = %f --- \n", max_temp);
         break;

      }

      rtn = its;
   }

   /* Terminate the thread
      Print the running statistic
    */
   for(int i = 0; i < thr_count; ++i){
        pthread_join(thr_kids[i], (void **) &rtnArray);
      printf("Thread %d has completed - user: %.4f s, system: %.4f s\n", i, rtnArray[0], rtnArray[1]);
      // return iteration time
    }

   // update final_diff

   final_diff = max_temp;
        printf("--- Final temp: %f ---\n", final_diff);
   return rtn;
    }
```

Workers thread

```
void *thr_func(void *arg) {

// (2) Add the worker's logic here
int x = *((int*)arg);
//Split the computation evenly
int start = x*(N/thr_count)+1;
int end = (x+1)*N/thr_count;
double diff = 0.0;
count = thr_count;


// used to return user time and sys time.
struct rusage usage;

if (end == N)
{
    end = end - 1;
}
//While not terminate
while(true){
   //find the max temp  diff in the set
    for(int i = start; i <end; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < N-1;j++){
            w[i][j] = 0.25 * (u[i-1][j] + u[i+1][j] + u[i][j-1] + u[i][j+1]);
            if(fabs(w[i][j] - u[i][j]) > diff)
                diff = fabs(w[i][j] - u[i][j]);
        }
   }

if(diff >= sum_temp[x]){
   sum_temp[x] = diff;
   printf("new temp for trial %d = %f\n", x, sum_temp[x]);
}
//Signal master thread to test the diff
count--;
if(count == 0){
   pthread_cond_signal(&mum);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mlock);
}
pthread_mutex_lock(&nlock);
/*Wait for the master instruction
if stop == true --> main thread tells workers can stop work
else stop == false --> run the loop again.
*/

pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &nlock);

//receive the instruction 
// stop is bool type 
if(stop){
printf("--- STOP!!! --- \n");
    break;
}
else if(!stop){
   printf("--- Continue ---\n");
    continue;
}

}

printf("Count = %d\n", count);
printf("\nThread%d: The max temp diff for the set between %d and %d is: %f\n", x,  start, end, diff);

/* terminate and return running statistic
   send to main thread
*/
rtnArray = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) *2);
rtnArray[0] = (usage.ru_utime.tv_sec + usage.ru_utime.tv_usec/1000000.0);
rtnArray[1] = (usage.ru_stime.tv_sec + usage.ru_stime.tv_usec/1000000.0);
pthread_exit(rtnArray);
return rtnArray;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a mutex between workers and main - here, a simple `join()` should suffice. Also, workers are started with the mutex locked by the main thread and then wait for a free mutex which will never happen - they'll never run.

Comment: My idea is since the worker needs to run serval times (one for each iteration). So I try to use condition variables. Thanks for your advice anyway!! @tofro

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** *In the main thread, how to "wait for all workers to finish their computation"?*
**A:** [pthread_barrier_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait) (see also [pthread_barrier_init](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init))

**Q:** *In the worker thread, how to "Signal master thread to test the diff"?*
**A:** No need for signal. Again, if the main thread waits at the barrier, it will continue after all threads have reached that barrier.

Your code needs only two barriers, there is no need for mutexes or condition variables.

Comment: The question required to use condition variable and mutex lock. Can I implement barrier method with c.v & lock?

Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Well, a barrier is basically a spinlock on a counter (number of threads) which will be consecutively decreased. After it hits zero, the lock will be released (unlocked) and all threads will continue. In case of a condition variable, every thread will decrese the counter and if not zero, will go into wait mode. The thread which sets the counter to zero, will signal all threads to wake up. So, either barrier or mutex and condition variable, both together makes not much sense (only if not separated, e.g. main thread do not participate in the barrier).

Comment: I saw this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053844/multithreading-implementation-of-jacobi-heat-distribution
Is it similar to implement the barrier?

Comment: Again, a barrier contains a _global_ counter (which has to be protected by a mutex) and every thread wanting to participate on that barrier has to decrease the counter. If the counter is not zero (yet) the thread has to suspend somehow (yield, sleep or wait on a condition variable). The thread which sets the counter to zero is responsible to notify (wake up) all the other threads (if they do not check the counter in succession already).

Comment: I have updated the code, can you have a look? Thank you!